# How to use an item in my off-hand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As of snapshot 15w31a, you can hold things in **both** of your hands.

I figured out that <kbd>F</kbd> lets you hold the item in your other hand. But how do I use this item? Can it even be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The item in your offhand can only be used for it's **right click** function (i.e. eating, placing blocks, blocking with shields).

Note that when you right click, the game first tries to use your main hand, and if the item in it does not have a right click function (or that function is inapplicable where you are targeting), checks your offhand. The sword can no longer be used for blocking since **15w33c**, so you can use things together with sword and most tools.

For the **left click** function, only your main hand item can be used.

Comment: As an example: You have a pick in your main hand and torches in your off hand. With left click you can break blocks as usual, but when you rightclick you will place torches, since a pickaxe has no rightlick functionality.

Comment: Technically, it uses your off-hand if right-clicking with your main hand does nothing *at the moment*. E.g. if you carry a block and try to place it inside your feet, your off-hand will be used. It's great for block-ladder dual-wield climbing.

Comment: @MrLemon Super handy observation!

Comment: @OrcJMR I should give credit where it's due: [Xisuma had a video on that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbni-CJWAqI).

Comment: Note that there are a few exceptions to this. The right click function of bows and fishing rods will not work in your offhand.

Comment: @colorfusion Bows can work from the off-hand when you have arrows in the main hand at least (source: Minecraft Wiki)

Comment: @PaulStelian A bow in offhand works fine now (but not a year ago, when that comment was written).

Comment: @col So it was a later change. Which snapshot? (if you know)

Comment: @PaulStelian Don't know, and I can't seem to access older snapshots.

Comment: @col My launcher (3rd party) can get those snapshots and make them available to the normal one.