# How to NOT use an item in my off-hand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There is a question on this website on how to use an item in your off-hand. [How to use an item in my off-hand?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232671/how-to-use-an-item-in-my-off-hand)

Thanks for the explanation there.

My question however is how to NOT use this item. Running around in the dark with a lamp in my off-hand, sometimes the lamp is placed on right click, and I don't have a pickaxe or something to break it to retrieve it.

Is there a way to prevent off-hand items being placed when there is no right-click function or an empty right hand?

Comment: Sorry to ask that but ... Why do you right click in the first place ?

Comment: @Fana: Eating? Opening doors? If you watch streams of [Joe Hills](https://www.twitch.tv/joehills), he usually carries a pane of green stained glass in his off hand as "green screen" background under his face cam (don't dig into how that's supposed to work technically, insanity lies that way). And him losing it by placing it somewhere accidentally all the time is a sort of running gag.

Comment: I removed the word "forum" from your post. This is NOT a forum and that's important to know. Please read the [tour].

Comment: Sorry Fabian. I mistook a forum to be a place where questions and views on a particular issue can be exchanged. Guess this is not such a place then?

Comment: @CharlieC: This is a Q&A site. The essential difference is "views on a particular issue..." - questions where *views* decide the answer get closed as "primarily opinion-based" here. No wishy-washy stuff like "what do you think of...". This is a site for concrete, factual, definite answers and solutions to actual problems you face. "Opinions* very rarely enter the picture, Some discussion over correctness of an answer is allowed in the comments, but in general, if you want a problem solved, ask here. If you want to *discuss* a problem, go to a forum.

Comment: So apparently this question cannot be answered here as there is no solution, That means that all the comments are just opinions. Better you remove the whole thread then.

Comment: @CharlieC: No, actually "There is no solution (definitively)" is a valid answer. Not all questions have answers, not all questions have answers available to the public, and you can't expect the asker to even know if their question is answerable before asking. In your case the answer is "no solution", there's nothing wrong with your question, it was just about clarification of policies here.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but the only sure method is "just don't do it." Either make sure the object in your off-hand isn't easily used by right-clicking or don't right-click anywhere where it would result in using it.

For example, if you carry a lantern, whenever you right-click, aim at an invalid location, somewhere where your lantern won't attach - empty air, a wall block with no blocks underneath or above, a top of a non-full block on which it can't be placed. Remembering about doing so is quite tricky.

Comment: This also happens regularly with a lantern in the off-hand, and using a wrench in the right hand to affect some block. Like with a Mekanism Logisitical Transporter when changing the end of the pipe to pull or push. The pipe changes and the lantern from the off-hand is placed on top, or next to it! 

Not really possible to "just don't do it".

Comment: @CharlieC In that case the answer is "don't hold anything in the off-hand." Just light up the place with torches and stuff.

Comment: I started moving the lantern back to the inventory, then placing it somewhere to light the area I was working, then affecting the pipe, then picking up the lantern again and moving it back to the off-hand. Quite a chore. Maybe I need to find a mod that gives a miner's helmet with an attached lamp. ;-)

Comment: @CharlieC: `F` to swap main and off-hand items (or move item from offhand to empty hotbar slot / from hotbar slot to empty off-hand).

Comment: Though that does not prevent the off-hand items being placed, that is an excellent solution SF. Saves a lot of time manually moving item from off-hand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I often have an arbitrary normal block in my offhand, like cobblestone, when I go mining or other things where I might have to pillar up or fill in spaces. Whenever I eat, I either stand at a wall and look at it or look at the ground or look in a direction where there's no block to target within my reach. That way you can't place it. This of course does not work with e.g. enderpearls.